# Converting java string to uppercase without using toUpperCase method

Tags: java, string, char, int

What I have so far

```
public String toUpperCase(String str)
{
    int strLength = str.length();
    String word = "";
    while (strLength > 0)
    {
        char newStr = str.charAt(strLength);
        Character.toUpperCase(newStr);
        Character.toString(newStr);
        word += newStr;
        strLength--;
    }
    return word;
}
```

I'm completely lost and my code is probably illogical. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to append the characters while you loop, rather than replacing the `newStr2` each time, so also make sure you declare the new `String` outside the while loop

Comment: `Character.toUpperCase(newStr1)`. There are no methods on primitives like `char`.

Comment: Store all the new characters in a char array and then, outside the loop append it all in a string.

Comment: Modifications you made are illogical. Do some research about return type of functions you are using.

Comment: @progy_rock Why not? That's quite a severe constraint considering the immense amount of Java libraries out here.

Answer (score 1):

The `Character.toUpperCase()` function returns a character. You have to hold that value in a char literal.

Plus, you should begin the loop at `strLength - 1` otherwise it'll throw a `StringIndexOutOfBounds` error. And, you should iterate till the index `0`. At present, you iterate from `strLength` till `1`.

Lastly, since you are iterating in the opposite direction, you should take care of the way you append the characters.

```
public String toUpperCase(String str)
{
    int strLength = str.length();
    String word = "";
    while (--strLength >= 0)
    {
        char newChar = str.charAt(strLength);
        newChar = Character.toUpperCase(newChar);

        word = newChar + word; //appending in reverse order
    }
    return word;
}
```

---

### NOTE

Since you are asked to write the function considering that the function doesn't exist, it would be less ironical to NOT use the `Character.toUpperCase()` method. Even I have used it. In that case, you can take a look at [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6662421/sam)'s suggestion. The above code will then have this modification:

```
char newChar = str.charAt(strLength);
if((int)newChar > 96 && (int)newChar < 123)
    newChar = newChar - 32;

//the if statement is the replacement of the Character.toUpperCase()
//function call
```

Answer (score 1):

To change string into uppercase without using toUpperCase(), then check below code.

```
if(ch>96 && ch<123)
{
            ch=ch-32;
            System.out.print( (char) ch);
}
```

check char small letter or not , if small then subtract it from 32

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the ASCII table.

char are integer, 'A' to 'Z' is 65 to 90 and 'a' to 'z' is 97 to 122.

So if you have a char between 'a' and 'z' you want to substract the difference betwin 'A' and 'a' to your char.

'a' - ('a' - 'A') = 'A'

'c' - ('a' - 'A') = 'C'

So you need to iterate on your string and do your math on each character.

```
public static char myUpper(char c){
    if (c >= 'a' || c <= 'z'){
        c = (char) (c - ('a' - 'A'));
    }
        return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally this is what I would do.

```
String newsentence =""; String question="HeLlo";
    String caps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for(int i=0;i<caps.length();i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<caps.length();j++) {
    if(question.equals(lowerCase.subString(j,j+1)){ newsentence+= (caps.subString(i,i+1); }

}} System.out.print(newsentence);
```

This is what I would do.

Comment: Just realized I should have another for loop to substring through the question variable